# How to add the same data to multiple users in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, insert

This is my bookmark table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookmark` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `note` text COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `owner` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `owner` (`owner`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=81 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_turkish_ci;
```

This is my user table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `bday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=75 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_turkish_ci;
```

What I want to do is when a user wants to share his bookmark with other users I want to insert the selected bookmark's data with the other user. In this case the selected bookmark's owner field will show different users which is the problem I stucked at. I don't know how to do this in this structure should I create a new table? if so, how? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a relationship table

```
rel_bookmark_user(id BIGINT AUTo_INCREMENT, ref_bookmark_id int(11), ref_user_id int(11));
```

so you can add anew user to the same bookmark

Comment: I didn't get it. should add this inside bookmark's table or create a new table?

Comment: no that is a new table, where you add the new user and the bookmark id, and here you can check if the user can access other bookmark other than his own